# Regular Expression to find word by specific symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```js
const str = 'DELETE FROM "organization" WHERE "name" = $1 AND "metadata" = $2 AND "id" = $3';
```

I need to find `"metadata"` word to modify it. I only know that there is `= $2` after `"metadata"` word.

```js
const regex = RegExp(/ = $2/); // just to show what I have
const foundWord = someMagicWithRegex(str, regex); // "metadata"
const newString = str.replace(foundWord, `${foundWord}::text`);
console.log(newString);

'DELETE FROM "organization" WHERE "name" = $1 AND "metadata"::text = $2 AND "id" = $3'
```

How `regex` should look? (if its possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```js
var str = 'DELETE FROM "organization" WHERE "name" = $1 AND "metadata" = $2 AND "id" = $3';
console.log(str.replace(/"[^"]*"(\s*=\s*\$2\b)/g, '"NEW METADATA"$1'));
```

The regex is `"[^"]*"(\s*=\s*\$2\b)`:

- `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, 0 or more chars other than `"` and then `"`
- `(\s*=\s*\$2\b)`  - Capturing group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured into this group):

  - `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `\$` - a `$` char (must be escaped)
  - `2\b` - `2` as a whole word.

Comment: Amazing :) answer .